# How do I list (po) the contents of a Swift Array?

Tags: debugging, swift, xcode6

Environment: Swift, Xcode 6

**How do I get a list (po) of data items of a Swift array?** 
The following is Swift code for building a simple array:

```
kindArray += "Two"
kindArray.append("Two")

var myStringArray: String[]
myStringArray = ["One", "Two"]
myStringArray.append("Three")
myStringArray += "Four"

var firstItem = myStringArray[0]
```

Here's the debug output:

```
(lldb) po firstItem
"One"

(lldb) po kindArray
Some
 {
  Some = 0x0ffb0000 {}
}
(lldb) po myStringArray
size=1
 {
  [0] = {
    core = {
      _baseAddress = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00000008
      _countAndFlags = 34718
      _owner = Some {
        Some = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x80000003)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All I'm getting is 'Some' and 'size'. 
I would like to show the contents.

Comment: I think `expr` is supposed to be better for dumping Swift types to the debugger console. (But I'm posting from my iPhone, where there's no LLDB to play with.) Also note you can type `repl` in the debugger to get an interactive Swift environment, much like a playground, with the current state of your debugging session.

Comment: I think they may not just not yet have implemented the kind of mapping they need to do for array and dictionary debugging in Xcode.

Comment: In both cases (repo & expr) I get the same 'po' result.  So I suspect this feature isn't fully implemented,

Answer (score 67):

Just do:

```
po print(myStringArray)
```

Comment: it's not working for global variable like `po print(self.currentOrder)`

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to take advantage of the `Printable` or `DebugPrintable` protocols. Simply print out the `description` or `debugDescription` property:

```
po myStringArray.description
po myStringArray.debugDescription
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: myStringArray: [(Square, 25), (Square, 16),...]     
------>
(lldb) po myStringArray.description
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4d03ee60).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation -------->
(lldb) po myStringArray
size=1
 {
  [0] = (0 = Swift.String @ 0x7fbd0e3d6f70, 1 = 0)
}  ------>
(lldb) po myStringArray.debugDescription
error: <REPL>:1:1: error: 'Optional<Array<(String, Int)>>' does not have a member named 'debugDescription'
myStringArray.debugDescription
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Are you running the code in your example above? It looks like you are storing something else in the array. I ran your code and my `po` statements work great.

Comment: I was able to do a println(); but not a po via debugger.  Perhaps the debugger isn't correctly set?  ...I'm using the standard debugger defaults.

Comment: I tried to access the first element of the array:                 let RicTuple = myStringArray[0]; but got the following error:             "'(String, Int)[]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'"

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee I think you are getting bad data into your array somehow. It is also potentially a bug in the compiler, but I am able to print out arrays of strings just fine (including with the code in your question)

Answer (score 3):

```
po myStringArray.map{ $0 }
```

if you have an array of custom objects

```
po myArray.map.{ $0.customProperty }
```