# Difference between Printable and DebugPrintable in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, protocols

Looking for a Swift equivalent of Cocoa's `description`, I found the following protocols in Swift: `Printable` and `DebugPrintable`.

What's the difference between these two protocols and when should I use each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 6 Beta (Version 6.2 (6C101)) I find that both println and debugPrintln use description if-and-only-if the class descends from NSObject. I don't see that either uses debugDescription at all but when run in a Playground debugPrintln outputs only to the Console and doesn't appear in the playground itself.

```
import Foundation

class Tdesc: NSObject, Printable, DebugPrintable {
    override var description: String {return "A description"}
    override var debugDescription: String {return "A debugDescription"}
}

class Xdesc: Printable, DebugPrintable {
    var description: String {return "A description"}
    var debugDescription: String {return "A debugDescription"}
}

let t = Tdesc()
let x = Xdesc()

t.description

let z: String = "x\(t)"

println(t)      // Displays "A description" in the Playground and Console

debugPrintln(t) // Displays nothing in the Playground but "A description" in the Console

x.description

let y: String = "x\(x)"

println(x)      // Displays "__lldb_expr_405.Xdesc" in the Playground and Console

debugPrintln(x)
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is an example class

```
class Foo: Printable, DebugPrintable {
    var description: String {
        return "Foo"
    }
    var debugDescription: String {
        return "debug Foo"
    }
}
```

This is how to use it.

```
println(Foo())
debugPrintln(Foo())
```

Here is the output with no surprises:

```
Foo
debug Foo
```

I didn't try this in a Playground. It works in an actual project.

The answer above was for Swift 1. It was correct at the time.

Update for Swift 2.

println and debugPrintln are gone and the protocols have been renamed.

```
class Foo: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "Foo"
    }
    var debugDescription: String {
        return "debug Foo"
    }
}

print(Foo())
debugPrint(Foo())
```

Comment: Strangely enough is doesn't work in a playground (in beta 7). println(Foo()) outputs "__lldb_expr_69.Foo" and debugPrintln(Foo()) outputs nothing.

Comment: Huh. Thanks for checking it in a Playground. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote anonymous person. Perhaps you'd like to add to the answer and/or point out what is wrong?

Comment: Here's an XCode screen dump showing that my example works. http://imgur.com/7PTktqB

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main difference is the property that's used to print. `Printable` has `description` and `DebugPrintable` has `debugDescription`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254220/887210

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH11-SW1

**Edit:**

Apparently print() and println() don't work properly with Printable and DebugPrintable:

```
struct TestPrintable : Printable {
  var description: String { return "Testing Printable" }
}

struct TestDebugPrintable : DebugPrintable {
  var debugDescription: String { return "Testing DebugPrintable" }
}

println(TestPrintable())      // -> "__lldb_expr_42.TestPrintable"
println(TestDebugPrintable()) // -> "__lldb_expr_42.TestDebugPrintable"
```

More information about this:

http://vperi.com/2014/06/04/textual-representation-for-classes-in-swift/

Comment: You use debugPrintln() to get the debugDescription. See my example above.