# Why is my Printable implementation not working in Swift playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Consider this code in a Swift playground:

```
import Cocoa
class Thing: Printable {
    let name: String
    init() {
        name = "something"
    }
    var description: String { return name }
}

let a = Thing()
println("hello, \(a)")
```

As an image:

[image]

Expected: I expect the last line to print "hello, something".

Observed: it prints "hello, __lldb_expr_1.Thing" as if I had not implemented the Printable protocol.

The code actually works in the context of a real iOS app where it prints "hello, something" using the Printable protocol as expected.

Why does this code not print what I expect in the playground? Is this a limitation of playgrounds?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a limitation of the playground, as noticed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27830622/1187415: *"I find that both println and debugPrintln use description if-and-only-if the class descends from NSObject."*

Comment: Interesting. Yes, it works in the Playground when I inherit from NSObject. But feels like it should also work without. I am following Session 404 “Advanced Swift” from WWDC 2014. It doesn’t talk specifically about Playgrounds but it does use this approach to log a Swift object that doesn’t inherit from NSObject.

Comment: Time to file another bug report :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this bug have been fixed in Swift 1.2
[image: swift-playground]