# What method/property does "xcrun swift" use for results?

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

My first guess was that it would be `debugDescription` or `description`, but with NSURL, I'm getting something funny:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ xcrun swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.30). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "X")
$R0: NSURL = "X -- ile:///private/tmp/"
```

It's not `debugDescription` or `description`:

```
  3> NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "X").debugDescription
$R1: String = "X -- file:///private/tmp/"
  4> NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "X").description
$R2: String = "X -- file:///private/tmp/"
```

Clearly, also, if you simply define `debugDescription` and `description` (like `class Foo` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691400/6453879)), it doesn't print those.  (It uses them for `print()` and `debugPrint()`.)

What is it printing in the repl by default, though?

Answer (score 2):

The REPL is an extension of lldb. As such, for classes and structs, it is printing the type summary after evaluating. You can find more information about that [here](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html).

You can create a custom type summary for a class. For example, I can enter:

```
class MyClass: NSObject
{

}

let myClass = MyClass()
```

Into the REPL, which prints:

```
myClass: MyClass = {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
    isa = __lldb_expr_45.MyClass
  }
}
```

I can then step out into lldb by typing `:` In lldb I can bind `MyClass` to a custom type summary by saying:

```
type summary add --summary-string "This is a MyClass" MyClass
```

I can drop back into the REPL by typing the command: `repl`

Now, when I say `let myClass = MyClass(),` I get:

```
myClass: MyClass = This is a MyClass
```

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting and useful, but I'm even more confused as to how my path `"X"` is coming out as `"X -- ile:///private/tmp/"` now!

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo in the type summary of `NSURL`, but I don't have any specific insight into how it got there.